# Angular html error in Mat select and mat option

Tags: angular

I am trying to run this code

```html
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="header-primary-text"> Response </mat- header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <!-- Code for new questions and dropdown - Ramki -->
  <!-- mat-form-field style="width: 48%" -->
  <div *ngIf="element.name == 'Select the complexity of Application'">
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="element.QuestionCode" placeholder="Select the complexity"
      <mat-option *ngFor="let qc of element.QuestionCode" value="{{qc}}">
        {{qc}} </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
```

I am getting error as follows:

> Unexpected closing tag "mat-option". It may happen when the tag has
>   already been closed by another tag. For more info see
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags
>
> ```
> ("-option *ngFor="let qc of element.QuestionCode" value="{{qc}}">
> {{qc}} [ERROR ->]</mat-option>
> </mat-select>
> </div>
> ```

Where am I going wrong?

I am new to Angular.. Any help is appreciated

Comment: This happens when Your HTML is not closed properly.

Comment: corrected code now check. Closing tag not properly closed.

Comment: The <mat-select> tag is not properly closed: the > is missing at the end (after the placeholder attribute).

Comment: HI Aviboy:Where can I find the corrected code ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and I fixed this way. It might help many of you who faced the same problem like me.

```
<div *ngIf="element.name == 'Select the complexity of Application'">
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]='"element.QuestionCode"' placeholder="Select the complexity"
      <mat-option *ngFor="let qc of element.QuestionCode" [value]='qc'>
        {{qc}} </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
```